# Youtube iframe API - origin parameter issue - origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

Loading/injecting a Youtube iframe using the Iframe API works as expected, however, the origin parameter which is appended to the src url contains an encoded URI e.g. `origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com` If a new `YT.Player` object is also created for an existing iframe on the page (with the correct origin `origin=https://www.test.com`) the `onReady` callback event is only being fired once.

Furthermore, when using the `playerVars` object to set an origin key/value, the API does not use this value as one would expect.

The origin is required for HTML5 postMessage and is an extra security measure. Hopefully this issue can be fixed soon?

Comment: Is this a question or are you reporting a bug?

Comment: @MarkWheeler it's a bug. I've raised it here as per the Youtube documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/players/support